# Plot theoretical inverise-chi-square distribution

Tags: r, probability, distribution, chi-squared

I want to compare my 'empirical' data with the theoretical *inverse-chi-square distribution*. How do I plot the theoretical distribution?

Assume the following data:

```
require(invgamma)
set.seed(10)
y<-rinvchisq(1000, 10)
```

which leads to an 'empitical' distribution as follows:

```
as.tibble(y) %>%
  ggplot(aes(y)) +
  geom_histogram(bins=100)
```

[image]

My gut tells me that I should use the `dinvchisq`-function that can be found in the `invgamma` package. But cannot fit it properly. Does anyone know how to tackle this matter?

**EDIT:**

Adding solution, thanks to @marvinschmit and @BenBolker.

```
require(invgamma)
set.seed(10)
y = rinvchisq(1000, 10)

x = seq(0,1, by=.001)
d = invgamma::dinvchisq(x, df=10)
df = data.frame(x=x,d=d)

as.tibble(y) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = y)) +
  geom_histogram(bins=100, aes(y=..density..)) +
  geom_line(data = df, aes(x = x, y = d), color = "blue")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a vector of quantiles for the `d...` density functions. I will call the quantile vector `x`:

```
x = seq(0,1, by=.001)
d = dinvchisq(x, df=10)
plot(x,d, type="l")
```

**Output:**

[image: output: chisq density]

Note that I used basic `R` plotting because a pretty ggplot is not relevant to the question. You can simply construct a dataframe `df=data.frame(x=x,d=d)` and use it for pretty ggplot plotting.

**EDIT:** Use `lines()` to superpose the theoretical distribution over an empirical histogram.

Comment: OP may be having some difficulty with densities vs counts ...

Comment: I think @BenBolker put the finger on my issue now. How do I adjust that so I can plot the theoretical distribution over my sampled one?

Comment: Do you need ggplot or can it be base R? Let me know and i supply the code.

Comment: Thanks! Preferably in ggplot. But whatever is easiest for you.

Comment: If you use `geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..))` for your data in ggplot then you'll get the results plotted on a density rather than a count scale: then you can overlay the curve @marvinschmitt suggests

Comment: @marvinschmitt You were probably looking for `plot(density(y), ylim=range(d, na.rm=T));lines(x, d, lty=2, type="l", col=2);legend("topright", c("empirical", "theoretical"), lty=1:2, col=1:2)` concerning the densities.